# Water gets really hot after 2 minutes in the shower for 5 minutes then goes normal

Tags: plumbing, water, shower

So I live in a big apartment building and this just started happening the past few weeks.  I'm not really sure what would cause it since I didn't touch anything plumbing and its not an old building.

Basically if I shower the temperature works normally and after 2 minutes the water just gets really hot.  Even if I move the setting to the coldest.  Then after 3-4 minutes it goes back to normal.  Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably some heat exchange between pipes happening at some point, or you're getting backflow from the water heater(s). You'll need to investigate with your building manager and a plumber. There's not much we can say with the limited information you've provided.